# I can't find a redirect code in wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a really hard time finding a redirect code from an old WordPress website which I haven't touched in years. I'm using iPage as the hoster. I had two domains, which if you typed `url1` it redirected to `url2` if you type `url2` it didn't redirect at all.

Problem is I can't find at all where I typed this code. I have tried finding this code by starting from the first file

I've tried:

Erasing all the code in

- `index.php` of `root`
- `index.php` of `themes/index.php`
- `front-page.php` of `themes/mytheme/front-page.php`

still, the page keeps redirecting, I also moved all the files from root to a subfolder named `all` so the page can't find any code. still was redirecting.

So then I assume was an iPage setting, which loaded before all the code, so I searched for "iPage redirect" and found something called `Domain Pointing Manager" my settings was empty.

I blocked javascript in my browser, and it keeps redirecting, so I assume this is a PHP code.

I took a look in .htaccess of root and didn't find any redirect neither.

I'm hoping someone gives some sense to this because I can't

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195186/discussion-on-question-by-noel-diaz-i-cant-find-a-redirect-code-in-wordpress-we).